# python tkinter application same text on multiple rows

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I'm extremely new to python and I decided to try to make some things to test how things work. But I couldn't find a way to make a text on a tkinter button take the place of 2 rows. Here's the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
hoho = 0
def lul():
    global  hoho
    hoho = hoho + 1
    print(hoho)
class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()


def createWidgets(self):
    self.hi_there = tk.Button(self, fg="green")
    self.hi_there["text"] = "Pressing buttons is fun, isn't it?"
    self.hi_there["command"] = self.lel
    self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def lel(self):
        lul()
root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

If you know a way please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood the question right but you can use `\n` in your string to print the text on a new line on the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
hoho = 0

def lul():
    global  hoho
    hoho = hoho + 1
    print(hoho)


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()


    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self, fg="green")
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Pressing buttons\n is fun, isn't it?"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.lel
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    def lel(self):
        lul()


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```